# remove special character inside words with regex

Tags: python, regex

i have text like this :  `some text 'elle m'a dit ce qu'elle voulait.<break></break>' some text`

I want the `'`  to be ignored when it's not between words

Result wanted :  `some text elle m'a dit ce qu'elle voulait.<break></break> some text`

I came up with this regex code : `\b(')\b`, but it's doing the opposite work and i get on output:

`some text 'elle ma dit ce quelle voulait.<break></break>' some text`

Comment: Is there any case where `'` is not at the begging of the text or on the ending of the text?

Comment: @blazej yes there is but in most cases it's in the middle of a sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
r"\B'|'\B"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bDcIaU/1). It matches a `'` that is not enclosed with word boundaries on both ends.

*Details*:

- `\B` - a position other than a word boundary position (as the next pattern is `'`, the `\B` means there must be start of string or any non-word char immediately to the left of the current location
- `'` - a straight apostrophe
- `|` - or
- `'` - an apostrophe
- `\B` - that is either immediately followed with a non-word char or at the end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mfmy9p):

```py
import re
text = "some text 'elle m'a dit ce qu'elle voulait.<break></break>' some text"
print( re.sub(r"\B'|'\B", '', text) )
# => some text elle m'a dit ce qu'elle voulait.<break></break> some text
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's working thanks wiktor, can you please explain this regex expression

Comment: @user16085212 I deciphered the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a million i didn't know that \B is the opposite of \b , still learning regex :)